# Centre of gravity and centroid

Tags: geometry, mathematics, applied-physics

Are the *geometric centre* & *centre of gravity* of a right angled triangle at **different** coordinates ?

Comment: Only if the object has uniform density

Answer (score 1):

For any triangle, both are at the average coordinates of the three vertices:
$(a+b+c)/3$.
This holds true for a triangle of uniform density.
And I am interpreting "center of gravity" as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#Center_of_gravity).

Comment: For any mass density and for any gravitational field?

Comment: @Diracology: Good point; will clarify.

Answer (score -1):

The both coordinates(COM&CG) of a plane surface of uniform mass density in uniform gravitational field are same.

Answer (score -2):

Centre of Gravity and Centre of mass of a body on surface of earth are same. But, the centroid depends on the dimensions of the body(triangle) but not on mass. Hence for a non uniform mass distribution the centroid doesn't coincide with Centre of Gravity.